Neovim debugger for multi-threaded c++ application
I know nvim-dap client supports decent debugging for C++. But in a multi-threaded environment once it hits a break point in another thread, we aren't able to start stepping in that thread. This is the only reason I have to use VSCode for some cases. Is there any debug adapter client that can handle this scenario, cause most debug adapters do support it as far as I'm aware.
mfussenegger/nvim-dap plugin doesn't plan on providing this functionality at least for the foreseeable future :(

before nvim-dap there is https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector . Bottom line, if there is somethinng missing in nvim-dap, go ahead and implement it.

I thought of implementing it but seems like a learning curve for which I don't think I'm ready yet. :\
